# What are these random characters in my URL and how did they get there?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0

https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/AppName/(S(fuzxravpfxmtjtifjcd5dt0n))/Views/Reports/Page01.aspx

What are the characters between /AppName/ and /Views/ and how did they get into my url? The url is actually https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/AppName/Views/Reports/Page01.aspx but that random string is being inserted somewhere in the process before the page is viewed.

We recently switched from in-process state management to using SQL Server. Nothing else about the application changed and we can't go back to in-proc.

What are these characters and can we hide them?

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

That is your SessionState ID since you are apparently using Cookieless SessionState.  You can adjust this in your web.config

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx#cookieless_topic2

Comment: And indeed you should adjust this, because Cookieless sessions bring a whole bunch of usability and security concerns.

Comment: Plus! Un-cacheability issues.